# Unable to change the text of a column name in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint website running in the server. Which has a column name text in different language. I want to change the text in English language, but this column doesn't have link to click on it and make it editable- it seems this is dead column.

Can you please suggest how can I change such column name of list in SharePoint 2010. Image screenshot is below

[image]

I believe this will be possible if we know where to modify in the database to change the text of column name. Please give your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used SharePoint Manager 2010 to do this text changes for the current sharepoint website.

Cheers!